# Having issue updating a Binding's value that is in a TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a TextField that I want to update when a stepper is used. If the value is 45.0 and the stepper changes to 2, then I want to divide 42 / 2 and update the value in the TextField to 22. However, the value remains unchanged and stays at 42. Any idea where's going wrong?

[image]

As you can see changing the steppers does not change the value of the textfield as I intend.

Here is my code that you can reproduce yourself. Thanks!

```
class StackOverFlowExampleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [StackOverFlowExampleModel]()
    init() {
        for _ in 0 ... 4 {
            var temp = StackOverFlowExampleModel(name: "Test", value: 45.0)
            items.append(temp)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct StackOverflowView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = StackOverFlowExampleViewModel()
    @State private var inFocus: Field?
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($vm.items, id: \.id) { $item in

            ExtractedTextField(inFocus: $inFocus, item: $item)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ExtractedTextField: View {
    @Binding var inFocus: Field?
    @State var numberOfPeople = 1
    
    @Binding var item: StackOverFlowExampleModel
    @FocusState private var focus: Bool
    @State var ogVal = Decimal()
    @State var val = Decimal()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Item", text: $item.name, prompt: Text("Item name"))
                    

                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                Spacer()

                TextField("Value", value: $item.value, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .focused($focus)
                    .onChange(of: numberOfPeople) { newValue in
                        
                        item.value = ogVal / Decimal(Double(newValue))
                    }
                    
            }
            if focus {
                HStack {
                    Stepper(value: $numberOfPeople) {
                        Text("Split between \(numberOfPeople) people")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            ogVal = item.value ?? 0.0
        }
        .focused($focus)
        .id(item.id)
        .onChange(of: focus) { _ in
            inFocus = .fieldId(item.id)     // << report selection outside
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct StackOverFlowExampleModel: Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: StackOverFlowExampleModel, rhs: StackOverFlowExampleModel) -> Bool {
        lhs.id != rhs.id
    }

    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var value: Decimal?
    var hasFocus: Bool = false
    var selected: (Bool, Color) = (false, .clear)
}
```

```
enum Field: Hashable {
        case fieldId(UUID)
    }
```

Comment: Right away, it looks suspect to me that you're overriding `==` for the model

Comment: @jnpdx Ah yeah. I shouldn't have included that for this example. That was for something else. However, removing that does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `Stepper` is not updating the value of the `TextField` because the code is trying to update the `item.value` property in the `onChange` closure of the `TextField`, but not in the `Stepper`.

Maybe try to modify the code:

```
struct ExtractedTextField: View {
    @Binding var inFocus: Field?
    @Binding var item: StackOverFlowExampleModel
    @FocusState private var focus: Bool
    @State var val = Decimal()
    @State var numberOfPeople = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Item", text: $item.name, prompt: Text("Item name"))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                
                Spacer()

                TextField("Value", value: $item.value, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .focused($focus)
            }
            if focus {
                HStack {
                    Stepper(value: $numberOfPeople, in: 1...Int.max) {
                        Text("Split between \(numberOfPeople) people")
                    }
                    .onChange(of: numberOfPeople) { _ in
                        if let value = item.value {
                            item.value = value / Decimal(numberOfPeople)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .focused($focus)
        .id(item.id)
        .onChange(of: focus) { _ in
            inFocus = .fieldId(item.id)     // << report selection outside
        }
    }
}
```

THe code will use the `onChange` closure of the `Stepper` to update the `item.value` property as soon as the #people changes. Also using `in` parameter of the `Stepper` to make sure that the value of `numberofPeople` is always greater than or equal to 1

Comment: That didnt work unfortunately

Comment: any error in the console? also could you send me the updated code which you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solution which will update your textfield

```
struct ExtractedTextField: View {
@Binding var inFocus: Field?
@State var numberOfPeople = 1

@Binding var item: StackOverFlowExampleModel
@FocusState private var focus: Bool
@State var ogVal = Decimal()
@State var val = Decimal()

@State var value = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            TextField("Item", text: $item.name, prompt: Text("Item name"))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            Spacer()
            
            TextField("Item", text: $value)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .focused($focus)
                .onChange(of: numberOfPeople) { newValue in
                    item.value = ogVal / Decimal(Double(newValue))
                    value = "$ \(item.value ?? 0)"
                }
                .onAppear {
                    value = "$ \(item.value ?? 0)"
                }
            
        }
        if focus {
            HStack {
                Stepper(value: $numberOfPeople) {
                    Text("Split between \(numberOfPeople) people")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear{
        ogVal = item.value ?? 0.0
    }
    .focused($focus)
    .id(item.id)
    .onChange(of: focus) { _ in
        inFocus = .fieldId(item.id)     // << report selection outside
    }
}
```

}